# Why isn't my css style changing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to change the color of the text using javascript but something as simple as this isnt working and I dont understand why..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <script>
      var y = document.getElementById('ya');
       y.style.color = "red";
   </script>

<p style="font-size:100px;" id="ya">
    hi
</p>

</html>
```

Comment: look at your browsers developer tools console for an error

Comment: move the script block below the p block

Comment: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX. This was the problem and now I understand why. The element was being called before the rest of the page even got to load giving an error saying the element was null. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4):

Try this, it's working. This is because the script now runs after the DOM element renders.

```html
<p style="font-size:100px;" id="ya">
    hi
</p>

<script>
  var y = document.getElementById('ya');
  y.style.color = "red";
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the javascript was loaded before your p tag. If you check the console you will see an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   
<p style="font-size:100px;" id="ya">
    hi
</p>
  <script>
      var y = document.getElementById('ya');
       y.style.color = "red";
   </script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The element `id` you were trying to find wasn’t in the DOM as your script runs before the DOM element renders.

Your DOM position should come first then Script to manipulate the DOM element.

There are two solution for this problem :

**1. Move your Script below the DOM.**

```
<p style="font-size:100px;" id="ya">
    hi
</p>
<script>
  var y = document.getElementById('ya');
  y.style.color = "red";
</script>
```

**2. use jQuery document.ready()**

```
<p style="font-size:100px;" id="ya">
    hi
</p>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var y = document.getElementById('ya');
   y.style.color = "red";
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

An Element with `id='ya'` is undefined at the time you wrote the JavaScript. Put the JavaScript in your head and use `onload = function(){/* code here */}` or `addEventListener('load', function(){/* code here */})` and it should work every time (Well maybe not the first way if you have multiple onloads. But there's a way around that by assigning onload to a var then executing after the other onload). Really I would use External JavaScript, so it's stored in your Clients cache, this will improve site performance. Just make sure you change your file name if you update your JavaScript, if your site is deployed, or just clear your cache if your still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

first you can check jQuery.min.js in included in your file
your code is fine.

test this one

```
   <script>
      var y = document.getElementById('ya');
       y.css("color", "red");
   </script>
```